# creating temporary tables in oracle in query

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

IN mysql you have something like this:

```
Select * from    (select * from t1, t2 where t1.c1=t2.c1 ) tbl1 ,tbl2
where tbl1.col1=tbl2.col2;
```

is there anything in like this in oracle, because when I am trying to do same thing in oracle I am getting this error :
invalid identifier "tbl1"."col1".

Comment: don't use `AS`.. also invalid identifier means that table does not have that column at all...check for typo

Comment: also, don't use the *...  spell things out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
Select tbl1.col1
from (select c1 as col1 from t1, t2 where t1.c1=t2.c1 ) tbl1 ,tbl2
where tbl1.col1=tbl2.col2;
```

[Here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/subqueries.php) you can find more information.

Comment: I removed AS from the query,actually I never had AS in my original query by mistake I kept it here,but still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select tbl1.*, tbl2.* 
from (
  select t1.c1 as col1, t2.* from t1, t2 where t1.c1=t2.c1 
) tbl1 ,tbl2
where tbl1.col1=tbl2.col2;
```

Because you join 2 tables * doesn't work. Use tbl1.* and tbl2.* instead.

As already suggested by Parado you also have to rename t1.c1 to col1 in your inner select.